# Developing website for iPad only - force all links to be opened in app mode

Tags: javascript, html, ipad, frame, frameset

I'm building a small website that will be always be viewed on an iPad, I am using the meta tag:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

And adding the site to the homepage to force the iPad to treat it as an app. This eliminates the address bar and back buttons etc...

I have the site inside a frame set, initially the site will load up an `index.htm` landing page which has links to other pages containing `<frameset>`'s and `<frame>`'s. Each page has a navigation frame and a frame for displaying content. The content of the second frame will be an external webpage.

I had a problem where launching the site in app mode and clicking on the links in the landing page would result in a new window being opened in safari - essentially it would break out of the app context and load up safari, i resolved this with:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('a').click(function (e) {
            window.location = $(this).attr('href');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Which keeps all links under my site loaded within the 'app'.

Now, here is the problem.

The frames that load the external webpages will obviously contain links, when clicking on these links in the frame this fires up safari and breaks out of the app context and the app goes back to behaving as it did before.

Is there a way of making sure that **all** links on the site open within the 'app', even those contained within the `<frame>` elements?

The overall goal here is to prevent the user from breaking out of the app and going off to do whatever they like on the net

Comment: I know this isn't a direct answer to your question, but if you are trying to prevent the user from breaking out of the app, what is stopping them from simply hitting the home button and going to safari from there to access the internet?

Comment: @Nick The iPad will be contained within a display case - it would cover the home button

Comment: if the iPad wll be used exclusively for this purpose, can't you simply uninstall Safari?

Comment: @Tip_Top That is a similar fix to what I already have for preventing anchors opening up safari. It wouldn't prevent links loaded within frames from using the default behaviour unfortunately.

Comment: Why use frames ? Just load the other contents with php/ajax ? You'll never need to load a new page so no new windows will be opened.

Comment: @Brainfeeder Sorry I should have mentioned but there is a requirement that we don't use any server side code (ridiculous I know) @Mr Lister Would the app still run? I thought that adding the `mobile-web-app-capable` meta tag just forced the site to open in fullscreen when launched as a app and still used safari under the hood

Comment: @DGibbs You still could load html file content with ajax. No server side language needed.
You would be able to make a `div` the target. Each time a link gets clicked, the new html would be loaded in the div. Safari will not need to open any other tabs with that method.

Comment: Gotta love serial downvoters..

Answer (score 0):

I know you state that it's a website, but it seems like you're making something which resembles an app and I'm tempted to suggest using phonegap. http://phonegap.com/

The reason is, you're not going to be able to prevent the links opening in safari. Although Brainfeeder makes a good suggestion with loading external html into a div, but I think you're still going to have the same issue when users click links from external sites inside that div.

With phonegap all you'll have to do is create a new project, dump your code as it is into the www folder and straight away you'll have an app you can deploy to your iPad.

But the main thing which made me suggest this is a feature called inAppBrowser which will let you specify links to open in a foreground webview, so that when a user is finished viewing, they just click done and are returned to your app. 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser

Appreciate it seems like a bit of overhead just to fix the safari issue, but might be worth considering.